# Unable to establish the Cassandra - Generic JDBC connection in AQUA Data Studio

Tags: cassandra, aqua-data-studio

Your server is not listening or accepting connections on 127.0.0.1:9042. Verify host and port information is correct

VM: 127.0.0.1:9042
JDBC URL :jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9042/quantum_cassandra
Driver:cdata.jdbc.cassandra.CassandraDriver
Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This error message in Aqua Data Studio indicates that your host/port is incorrect, or your server is not listening on that port, or a firewall is blocking network access to it.

You just need to make sure your server is running correctly and no firewall is blocking your connection. Note that IP address 127.0.0.1 is a local loopback and is only accessible on the same machine and not remotely.

Comment: But I can connect using the DBeaver .In Aqua data studio, I am not able to do that.

Comment: Did you register a native Cassandra Server Registration or JDBC Driver ? AD Studio has native connections. Look at this link https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation18/page/Apache-Cassandra/Apache-Cassandra